# Installing Worklight Server v506 with Oracle and Liberty does not create the expected directory structure

Tags: oracle, ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty

For example: When installing Worklight with Derby+Liberty, a build tree is created under C:\ProgramData\IBM\Worklight\WAS85liberty-server...

My installation is not creating this directory structure.

Anyone could help me? Please, let me know if you need more information.

Tks in advance!
Gustavo.

Comment: From your internal thread @ IBM Connections, it seems the below answered your question. Could you please mark as Answered? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you install Worklight Server 5.0.6.x on Windows 7/8, with administrator permissions, and make the application server choice "Install WebSphere Application Server Liberty Profile", a directory `C:\ProgramData\IBM\Worklight\WAS85liberty-server` will be created. It will contain the data portion of a WebSphere Application Server Liberty Profile installation; the program portion is under `<WORKLIGHT_INSTALL_DIR>/server`.

Possible reasons why the directory is not there:

- If you are on Windows XP, the expected location is at `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\IBM\Worklight\WAS85liberty-server`.
- If you made the choice "Use a pre-installed application server", Worklight Server will not create an application server by itself, but instead use the one you indicated.
- If you don't have administrator permissions or did not run Installation Manager with "Run as administrator", and if your Windows has [User Account Control (UAC)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905330.aspx) enabled, Windows will place the files elsewhere on the disk.